# Reverse proxy to bypass X-Frame-Options

Tags: nginx, iframe, reverse-proxy, x-frame-options

Good evening everyone,

I have developed a web app for our school that is loaded into a kiosk app on ChromeOS and Windows so that students can take digital tests and exams in a protected environment.

[image]

The web app also allows you to consult sources, these sources are links to, for example, a news site, wikipedia, you name it..

Unfortunately, many external links do not work because they are loaded into the web app via iFrame. And nowadays many websites do not allow this by passing this in the headers such as x-frame options.

I had hope at https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass but unfortunately it no longer works.

I also come to the conclusion that a reverse proxy could offer a solution here, but I have no experience with this and research does not make it any easier for me. Or are there even better/other solutions?

As a test I was able to realize through the following that google.be can be loaded within an iFrame, however I encounter 2 problems that I hope I can find a solution for this way.

**Issue 1: Images and CSS not loading**

The content links to the proxy server, of course that content does not exist on the reverse proxy server.

[image]

**Issue 2: Every teacher can create exams/tests with their own external sources, it is impossible to add all those external URLS to the reverse proxy every time**

That's why I thought of getting the url for the proxy_pass from the url of the reverse proxy url.

Reverse proxy url: http://sitekiosk.xyz/bypass/google.be
google.be gets used in the proxy_pass

Reverse proxy url: http://sitekiosk.xyz/bypass/wikipedia.be
wikipedia.be gets used in the proxy_pass

And so on...

```
    location /bypass {
            proxy_set_header Host www.google.be;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass https://google.be/;

            proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;
            proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";
    }
```

Is this technically possible? Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to go through this!

My apologies for my Google Translate English :-)